# How to add separately google map at react native iOS project ? (without Objective-C/Swift component support)

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native, mobile-development

Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/ no library for react native 
!

Comment: check https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

Comment: @Jickson they are used by Apple maps check this out .. i  need to google ANDROID map

Comment: That library has support for using google maps in ios. Please check this pull request https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/pull/548

Comment: thnak you bro. i will try and let u knw.